# Using flexbox on table header <th> elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a scenario which requires a complex layout within table header `<th>` elements. I want to approach the problem by making the `<th>` elements a flex container.

However, if I start with this minimal example

[image]

and change the `<th>` elements to `display: inline-flex`, the table becomes:

[image]

I.e., the column width of the header no longer matches the column width of the `<td>` elements.

How can I make use of flexbox inside the header without messing up column rendering?

**Edit to clarify the use case**: My `<th>` elements will eventually contain multiple elements, with left+right alignment (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089820/right-align-and-left-align-text-in-same-html-table-cell)). In addition I want to be able to control the stretch behavior (that's why flexbox instead of just floats).

---

Example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bluenote10/ga1suj9y/10/):

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="column-header">A</th>
      <th class="column-header">B</th>
      <th class="column-header">C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-header {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: Can you use a wrapper-element inside `th` that has `display: flex`?

Comment: @insertusernamehere I would have preferred to avoid a wrapper, but if that is that is the only solution it is fine as well.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? - https://jsfiddle.net/mjyzs4o2/ - I am also not sure why you would want to use display flex in a table as using divs would be better

Comment: @Andrew No that's not what I'm looking for. I don't want to make the `<tr>` a flex, but the `<th>`. In my use case I need to align various things in each `<th>`, multiple left aligned text elements, right aligned symbols, some of them should stretch etc.

Comment: @bluenote10 you can put your `<td>` also as `display:inline-flex` and then add a min-witdh

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My  elements will eventually contain multiple elements, with left+right alignment. In addition I want to be able to control the stretch behavior (that's why flexbox instead of just floats).

In that case, you need to use a `div` inside each `th` and flex *that.*

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column-header div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="column-header">
        <div><span>A</span><span>A</span></div>
      </th>
      <th class="column-header">
        <div><span>B</span><span>B</span></div>
      </th>
      <th class="column-header">
        <div><span>C</span><span>C</span></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Would be interesting to know why that is needed, is there a rule that what can and what cannot be a flex?

Comment: In tables, yes. You're breaking the layout algorithm essentially. A `div` is semantically null so it's useful as a wrapper without actually meaning anything.

Comment: I'm asking because I was searching for official specs on that and couldn't find anything. There are [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48749336) that suggest that `display: flex` is valid for `th`.

Comment: It's valid, yes, but that's not the issue. The issue is that giving a cell `display:flex` overrides the default of `display:table-cell` (set via the user agent default stylesheet). That is an essential piece of the table layout algorithm, as Paulie_D was saying. Without it, you would have to override the display property on the parent  `<tr>` element and set `display:table` on the thead's sibling tbody element(s). **And** you would most likely need to set an explicit width on the cells of each column.